# Ionic 2 Html elements not showing in the browser

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 project and have built my front page so far which is fine.

The problem appears when I try to insert a common **footer directive** which I created myself.

What bothers me the most is the fact that the footer tag, which I have named **footer-line** appears in the console when I inspect my page, but the elements of
my **footer_panel.html** file don't.

Any ideas why this might be?

The code for my **component:**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FooterService } from '../Services/footer_service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'footer-line',
        templateUrl: '../View/footer_panel',
        providers: [FooterService]
    })


    @Injectable()
    export class Footer {

    }
```

The code for my **FooterService:**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Footer} from '../Directives/footer.component';

@Injectable()
export class FooterService {

    insertFooter() {
        return Footer;
    }
}
```

The code in my **HomePage.html** file

```
<ion-content>
(...)
</ion-content>
<footer-line></footer-line>
```

The **footer-line** tag appears when I inspect my page in the browser. However, the dummy elements inside my footer_panel.html file do not. :(

My HomePageComponent:

```
export class Question {
id: number;
question_content: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code? Code of the component where you add the directive, and anything you deem relevant

Comment: @PierreDuc yes, 2minutes! :)

Comment: @PierreDuc I have added the relevant code!

Comment: Why are you using a service to insert the `Footer`? Never seen that.. Can you also paste your HomePageComponent code?

Comment: @PierreDuc What kind of issues might this cause? I see your point. Might change that in the future! And, yes, have uploaded it now! My HomePageComponent only cosists of a single Question class which has an id and a string for content which I use in another component, having an array of questions.